# Comparing Python Multiprocessing and Multithreading on 100K Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a folder with 100K files in it, totaling 50GB. The goal is to read each file run some regex to store data. I am trying to run test to see which approach, Multithreading or Multiprocessing, will be most ideal.

The server I am using has 4 cores and 8GB RAM.
Without any multithreading it takes around 5 minutes to complete the task.

```html
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
threads= []

def read_files(filename):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
             text = f.read()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
     for filename in glob.iglob('/root/my_app/my_app_venv/raw_files/*.txt', recursive=True):            
         threads.append(executor.submit(read_files, filename))
```

Multithreading Averages out to 1 min and 30 secs.

Now I am trying to setup test for Multiprocessing and use the 4 cores on the server and not getting anywhere.

```html
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
import time
import queue 


def read_files(tasks_to_accomplish):
    while True:
        try:            
            filename = tasks_to_accomplish.get_nowait()
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
        except queue.Empty:
            break    


def main():    
    number_of_processes = 4
    tasks_to_accomplish = Queue()    
    processes = []

    for filename in glob.iglob('/root/my_app/my_app_venv/raw_files/*.txt', recursive=True):        
        tasks_to_accomplish.put(filename)
        
    # creating processes
    for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=read_files, args=(tasks_to_accomplish,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # completing process
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `concurrent.futures`, I'll recommend using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which sits on top of `multiprocessing` similar to how `ThreadPoolExecutor` sits on top of `threading`. These classes have nearly-identical APIs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor